# Pinescript: Cannot modify global variable in function

Tags: global-variables, pine-script

Here is a snippet of my pinescript version 5 code and I am trying to get the local "crossed" condition to modify the global variable "crossed" but I keep running into the error "cannot modify global variable in function".

```
var bool crossed = na // Declare a global variable for the crossed condition

method puts(bool mode, array<line> a, line l) =>
    crossed := false // Reset the global "crossed" variable
    if mode == true
        if a.size() == 500
            line.delete(a.shift())
        a.push(l)
    if mode == false
        for j = a.size() - 1 to 0 by -1
            x = line.get_x2(a.get(j))
            y = line.get_y1(a.get(j))
            if bar_index - 1 == x - 1 and not (high > y and low < y)
                line.set_x2(a.get(j), bar_index + 1)
            if bar_index - 1 == x - 1 and (high > y and low < y)
                crossed := true // Set the crossed condition to true
```

Please help. Thank you.

I tried changing the global variable to a mutable one but it also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear. You cannot modify global variables in functions. Just use a temporary variable and return it. Then use the return value to change your global variable's value.

```
var bool crossed = na // Declare a global variable for the crossed condition

method puts(bool mode, array<line> a, line l) =>
    _crossed = false
    if mode == true
        if a.size() == 500
            line.delete(a.shift())
        a.push(l)
    if mode == false
        for j = a.size() - 1 to 0 by -1
            x = line.get_x2(a.get(j))
            y = line.get_y1(a.get(j))
            if bar_index - 1 == x - 1 and not (high > y and low < y)
                line.set_x2(a.get(j), bar_index + 1)
            if bar_index - 1 == x - 1 and (high > y and low < y)
                _crossed := true // Set the crossed condition to true
    _crossed

crossed := // Call your function here
```

Comment: Hi thank you for you help.  I am sorry as I am a beginner in pinescript coding. What do you mean by this line? I just want the "crossed" condition to return true  if bar_index - 1 == x - 1 and (high > y and low < y)
crossed := // Call your function here